# Can you use a comma in a PHP array key?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wanting to make a PHP array and use people's names as keys mapping to employee ID numbers. Example:

```
$staffID = array(
   "Doe, Jane" => 124, 
   "Smith, John" => 876
);
```

I'd like to keep them LastName, FirstName so that I can easily peruse down the list later on. I'm concerned about those commas in the keys though. Is this valid in PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they're just strings. You can have any valid string (or integer) as an array key.